# Por que um array dinâmico funcionou sem o uso de malloc()?

Tags: c, array, memória, alocação, stack

Segue o trecho de código a seguir:

```
int main(void)
{
    int tam, vet[tam];
    printf("\ndigite tam: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);
    return 0;
}
```

Eu não sabia que isso funcionava, pois estou digitando o tamanho do vetor em tempo de execução. Para mim, essa era uma das funcionalidades do `malloc()`, pois neste caso, esperava a entrada do usuário, pegava o tamanho digitado e faria um `malloc()` com esse tamanho. Mas pelo que parece, o C já faz isso automaticamente?

O que acontece neste caso? O que seria mais indicado a fazer em casos com este?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seu código não faz alocação como você imagina, e está cometendo um grave erro. Esse código está longe de estar fazendo o que você acha que está.

Você está reservando memória para `vet` com uma quantidade de elementos indeterminada. Sim, porque você declarou `tam` mas não colocou nenhum valor para ela. Então o valor que estiver na posição de memória de `tam` será o tamanho de `vet`. Certamente a informação que está lá é um lixo. Pode ser que seja zero e não reserve memória para `vet`. Pode ser que seja um número bem grande e reserve vários KB ou MB de memória sem que você precise disso.

Você só obtêm um valor para `tam` depois que a variável `vet` está declarada.

O que talvez você não tenha entendido é que C deixa você fazer o que quiser com a memória. Se funcionar por coincidência, coitada da sua aplicação. Em C você tem que ter certeza que tudo está funcionando corretamente. Fazer um teste e achar que está funcionando é um perigo. Funcionou em uma situação específica. A próxima execução pode não funcionar, a execução em outro computador pode não funcionar. Apesar disto ser especialmente importante em C, é algo que vale para qualquer linguagem. **Testar e funcionar não garante que o programa esteja correto**, especialmente em C onde existe muito [comportamento indefinido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) ([resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101)). Infelizmente há um pensamento disseminado que acha que um simples teste é suficiente.

Uma possível implementação correta:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int tam;
    printf("\ndigite tam: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);
    int vet[tam];
    printf("%d", vet[0]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HgLq6f). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/awaqsrpl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/SizeInRuntime.c).

Note que estou apenas fazendo o que você pretendia. Não estou armazenando nada no *array*.

Se o valor digitado estourar o tamanho da pilha, já era também.

Veja um [exemplo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#Examples) como alocar na *stack*.

Answer (score 4):

*Arrays* com tamanho variável são permitidos desde o `C99`, como você pode ver [aqui](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Segundo o mesmo link, esses *arrays* funcionam como qualquer outro de tamanho que e uma expressão constante, então tem o mesmo funcionamento de

```
int v[10];
```

Além disso, eles não funcionam como um array alocado com `malloc`, já que estes são alocados no *heap* enquanto os *arrays* de tamanho variável são alocados na pilha, mas com endereço desconhecido em tempo de compilação.

Comment: Então o `C99` permite que declare variáveis em quanto o programa executa ? `C99` seria mais alto nível que o `C90` e `C89`

Comment: voce nao esta declarando variaveis enquanto o programa executa, voce esta determinando o tamanho do array que ja esta declarado e sera criado em tempo de execucao.

Comment: `C99` não permite declaração de variáveis em tempo de execução. Ele permite que o tamanho de um vetor seja determinado em tempo de execução.

Comment: @LucasVirgili vale complementar que como `tam` não foi inicializado no momento da declaração da variável `vet`, temos um `undefined behavior` neste código. Compilando com a flag `-Wall` no gcc deve exibir a warning variável não inicializada.

Comment: ah sim, eu ignorei o codigo dele para responder a pergunta. de fato o vetor tem tamanho indefinido.