# Alocação dinâmica de memória X vetor

Tags: c, array, memória, alocação

Estava estudando esse assunto em C, e na maioria dos lugares que eu procuro, um dos exemplos de utilização desse recurso é quando você vai criar um vetor cujo tamanho você não conhece. Exemplo:

```
int main() {

    int num = 0, i = 0, *vetor;

    printf("Digite a quantidade de números que deseja armazenar: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    vetor = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * num);

    for(; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Digite um valor inteiro para o %dº elemento do vetor: \n", i);
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("O %dº elemento do vetor é: %d\n", i, vetor[i]);
    }

    free(vetor);

    return 0;
}
```

Mas, eu posso reescrever o programa da seguinte forma, sem usar alocação dinâmica, e ele vai continuar funcionando:

```
int main() {

    int num, i = 0;

    printf("Digite a quantidade de números que deseja armazenar:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int vetor[num];

    for (; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Digite um valor inteiro para o %dº elemento do vetor: \n", i);
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("O %dº elemento do vetor é: %d\n", i, vetor[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Qual é a diferença que a alocação dinâmica faz nesse caso? Existe alguma situação em que não se tem alternativa a não ser alocar dinamicamente? E qual seria a diferença entre esses dois?

```
vetor = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * num);


vetor = malloc(sizeof(int) * num);
```

Comment: Não precisa fazer o typecast do malloc.

Comment: Na verdade é praticamente um erro fazer isto em C. Mas é uma dessas coisas que as pessoas nunca vão aprender porque tá cheio de exemplo ensinando errado.

Comment: Melhor ainda que `apontador = malloc(elementos * sizeof (tipo))` é `apontador = malloc(elementos * sizeof *apontador)` pois não precisa verificar se o tipo bate certo com o tipo definido.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A chamada alocação dinâmica é feita no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Isto tem implicações no [tempo de vida possível do objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101). Estamos neste local, ele sobrevive ao fim da função, ele não estoura ou sobrecarrega a pilha da aplicação e dá mais controle até quando está disponível.

De um modo geral sempre é possível alocar dinamicamente, só não é desejável, ela tem diversos problemas que podem ser vistos nos *links* aqui postados. Esta é uma escolha que deve ser feita com parcimônia, só quando realmente é necessária e traz vantagens.

Neste exemplo específico existe uma razão para usar a alocação dinâmica: o objeto pode ser grande demais. Quando o tamanho é desconhecido pelo programador ele deve ir pelo caminho mais seguro. E neste caso específico a alocação dinâmica não traz desvantagens reais (não sei se diria o mesmo se o exemplo mudar, mesmo que pouca coisa). Não dará problemas nos testes normais que alguém faria com poucos elementos, mas com 1 milhão provavelmente daria. Já 1 bilhão em alguns casos poderá dar erro na alocação dinâmica também.

Veja mais:

- [Ponteiro de char ou array de char?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116333/101)
- [Por que um array dinâmico funcionou sem o uso de malloc()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35149/101)
- [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).